# SailsJS returning all data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have User model in my Sails app which of course has password. So when I create a new user Sails responds with json containing all the data of the newly created user including the hashed password. Is there a way to prevent Sails from outputting certain fields like the password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You just need to override the toJson function for the model, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
  name: 'string',
  password: 'string',
  // Override toJSON instance method
  // to remove password value
  toJSON: function() {
    var obj = this.toObject();
    delete obj.password;
    return obj;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer and should be accepted. This is what i'm using currently.

Answer (score 1):

Add in the model:

```
afterCreate: function(attrs, next) {
    delete attrs.password;
    next();
}
```

Comment: Does it not delete the password from the model ?? How will you authenticate further ?